# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint error on import of Data

Tags: duplicates, key, constraints, primary-key

I have a table in SQL Server called Services. It has a primary key on the Service_ID field.
I deleted some data and am trying to reimport data from a CSV file.
I am getting the errors below. It mentions a violation of Primary Key.
However if I query the table searching for a record with that Service_ID value then it does not find it - results are empty. So why am I getting this error?

- Copying to [dbo].[Services] (Error)
  Messages
  Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Services'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Services'. The duplicate key value is (538629).".
  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination - Services.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination - Services.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - Services" (90) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (103). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - Services_csv returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate key was in my import data not the table.